# I can't style my customized menu in my wordpress website

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu

I am having this problem where I created my website first, with a menu in my header.php page.
And then I wanted to transform my website into a wordpress website, so I did what I had to do, but the problem is that I still can't figure out a way to transform the navigation menu in header.php into a menu that works on wordpress.

I have tried all solutions given by the wordpress tutoriels as well as some forums, but everything I try creates an ugly menu on top of my desired menu that is not even clickable.

I was able to create a menu location or whatever that is,and when I created the menu in the dashboard, I got this created menu on top of my desired menu. When I hover my mouse over my desired menu(in the following code: main_menu), nothing even happens.

Here is my header.php:

```
    <?php
/**
 * The Header template for our theme
 *
 * Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <div id="main">
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Thirteen
 * @since Twenty Thirteen 1.0
 */
?><!DOCTYPE html>

<!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="ie ie7" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="ie ie8" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 7) | !(IE 8)  ]><!-->
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<!--<![endif]--><head>
<?php /* Get our main menu Navigation bar */ ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'navigation', 1 ); ?>
<?php /* Get our top menu Navigation bar */ ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'navigation', 2 ); ?>


<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu', 'container_class' => 'main_menu' ) ); ?>


    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title><?php wp_title( 'entendrelimage', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
    <link rel="profile" href="http://www.entendrelimage.univ-paris1.fr/‎">
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'entendrelimage_url' ); ?>">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
        <header>
        <div id="main_menu">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#page2">Décryptage</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page3">Symboles</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <br/ class="annuleFloat">

        <ul id="recherche">
                <li><a href="www.google.com"><img id="glo" src="<? bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/glosaire_off.png" alt=""/></a></li>
                <li><img src="<? bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/ligne_top_right.png"/></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img id="rech" src="<? bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/recherche_off.png" alt=""/></a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="logo">
            <a href="#page1"><img src="<? bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/logo.png" alt=""/></a>
            <br/ class="annuleFloat">
        </div>
        </header>
<!-- #masthead -->

        <div id="container">
        <div class="main">
```

and this is the part of code that I put in functions.php:

```
    function register_my_menu() {
  register_nav_menu('header-menu',__( 'Header Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' );
```

So if anybody can tell me the problem it would be great!! I am desperately stuck at this one

Answer (score 0):

OK, I don't know if I am really understanding the issue but I will do my best to answer and give a solution. Basically: on your "first" (old) site, you had a menu, and now you want to remake it in Wordpress, and style it so it looks and feels as good as the old one.

No problem. On the backend of Wordpress, go to Appearance > Menus and create a new menu. Name it "header-menu" if you want. Put any of the new pages you've made in WP into it, or just make custom links to the pages you want (#page2, http://www.google.com, etc).

Now back on your .php page, put this code you had in the header

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu', 'container_class' => 'main_menu' ) ); ?>
```

into the main body of the page (maybe in the main-menu div?). It outputs the menu "header-menu" so it should be inside the page html. This might have contributed to the "can see but can't click it" problem. I don't think you need to mess with anything in functions.php to get a menu working. After you have it on the page, just take a look and style the css how you want.